# Include jQuery library in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to include a jQuery plugin (TreeGrid, http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/) inside an AngularJS web app.
I created a new custom directive, like this:

```
var app = angular.module('treegrid', []);

app.directive('treegrid', [function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            jQuery('.tree').treegrid(); 
        }

    };
}]);
```

I've included the directive inside the root module and called the jQuery library inside index.html .

By the way, applying the directive to the table tag does nothing; instead, if I write the function

> $('.tree').treegrid();

inside the onclick attribute of a button tag, it does work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just don&#39;t do it. It is unconventional.. You should never edit your DOM when you are working with a Virtual DOM

Comment: @FelixGaebler how can I include this library instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
<table treegrid>
<tr class="treegrid-1">
    <td>Root node</td><td>Additional info</td>
</tr>
<tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1">
    <td>Node 1-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
</tr>
<tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-parent-1">
    <td>Node 1-2</td><td>Additional info</td>
</tr>
<tr class="treegrid-4 treegrid-parent-3">
    <td>Node 1-2-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
</tr>
```

```
app.directive('treegrid', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A'
        ,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(elem);
            (elem).treegrid();
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: @robertotI have updated my code. I have tested my PC.it is now working fine. if any problem please let me know.

Comment: @robertot is it working? Can you please mark this answer correct if answered is useful

Comment: @robertot Thanks